# Add Product Images with Shopify API

Tags: shopify

We have a bunch of disassociated product images in our Shopify store that support could not re-associate. I set up a Postman collection runner to update all these missing images, and it seems to be working in our test environment....

Except, the API call is replacing the default product image with a new image rather than adding the image. I'm using a standard PUT request to the API using the example in their API docs:

```
PUT /admin/api/2019-04/products/#{product_id}.json
```

```js
 {
  "product": {
    "id": 632910392,
    "images": [
      {
        "src": "http://example.com/rails_logo.gif"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I get that it's an array I'm sending in, so I'm thinking it's overwriting the array each time rather than adding a new element. I tried using a single element variable of "image" in the JSON but that didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add the image use **ProductImage** resource instead of **Product** resource.

[Product Image Documentation](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/products/product-image#create)

```
POST /admin/api/2019-04/products/#{product_id}/images.json
{
  "image": {
    "src": "http://example.com/rails_logo.gif"
  }
}
```

Comment: My bad - issue was on my end. Your suggestion worked!